# Not getting id from other collection using mongodb and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am adding products under particular `userId` but not getting `userId` from other collection.

### api.js

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( {
        "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
        "Brand": json.Brand,
        "Color": json.Color,
        "Image": json.Image,
        "Price": json.Price,
        "Rating": json.Rating,
        "Description": json.Description,
        "Category": json.Category,
        "Url": urla,
        **"userId":db.collection('users').findOne()[0]._id,**
   }, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
        callback(result);
  });
};
        
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  insertDocument(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: how are you passing `userId` into mongodb ?

Comment: "userId":db.collection('users').findOne({"name": "admin"})._id, like this i am passing

Comment: I think `MongoClient` does not support another query in first query. It inserts `json` document. Try to fetch user first from db, then pass `"userId" : "1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to request the user from the datbase after inserting it.
e.g. based on your code the following should work:

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
    // Based on your code we assume that you have only one user in the database. Otherwise you have to do a find for a specific user.
    db.collection('users').findOne(function (err, user) {
       if (err) { return callback(err); }
       db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( {
            "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
            "Brand": json.Brand,
            "Color": json.Color,
            "Image": json.Image,
            "Price": json.Price,
            "Rating": json.Rating,
            "Description": json.Description,
            "Category": json.Category,
            "Url": urla,
            "userId": user._id
       }, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
            // Below I am passing the error as a first param to your callback. You can implemented as you wish, but it is a convention to use error as a first param.
            callback(err, result);
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: okay i got it. Then how do i pass userId to "proInfo" collection.

Comment: @HemanthkumarHJ I edited my answer so you first fetch your user (based on your code you have only one and therefore you do findOne) and pass the id to your insert query.

Comment: and one more thing is search UserId and its products